# VS2022 Disable Move Cursor on Search

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Is there any way to disable the cursor from moving in the file as I enter a search term?  Specifically, the cursor shouldn't move until I press enter in the search widget or I select the "Find Next" option.

This would have to be the most annoying "feature" I have ever come across in Visual Studio.